# php form. form validation. name chacking

Tags: php, forms

I have 1 problem here about validate name in HTML form using PHP. i have done all code but have 1 problem:

If user input " " (space) it mmust return error message that it is incorect name and user must inpput real name using a-z or A-Z, so if someone have an idea how to make an alghorithm or it is a built-in function for this please help me

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `trim()` on the input to get rid of white space (e.g. the " ")
2. Use `strlen()` to see if it's zero

So, let's say you get the user's input as a POST variable... e.g. `$name = $_POST['name']`. Try this:

`if(strlen(trim($name)) === 0) {
    // do stuff to tell user their name is invalid
}`

**A better idea**
Use a regex

`$legal_username_regex = "/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[._-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/";`

`if (preg_match($legal_username_regex, $new_username)) {
    // do stuff for a valid username
} else {
    // do stuff for an invalid username
}`

Comment: If this answered your question, please "accept" it, or leave further details in the comments for clarification.